# Copy files between two windows machines on seperate domains

Tags: windows, active-directory, copy, copying

I need to copy several database backups between two computers.

The source computer initiates the copy and is a Windows 2000 pc and is a member of domain1.

The destination machine is running Windows Server 2000 and is a member of domain2.

The machines are on separate networks physically connected via a firewall.

The files are currently copied via ssh with http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/ installed on the destination machine.

There is no need to encrypt the contents during the copy, however the passwords should not be sent in the clear.

I am looking for a way to copy the files without having to install a server on the destination.

I specifically need help with how to set up the permissions and what ports would need to be opened on the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably keep using scp/sftp for transfer. Using that requires only port 22 open, which you already have.

You could set up the transfer with Task Scheduler and an scp/sftp CLI client, there are many out there it seems.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use plain Windows networking? Authentication is encrypted and you need no additional software.

You'll need to open ports for NetBIOS (135-139) and SMB (445).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a VPN between the two machines and then use any of the many copy programs. My preference for such tasks is Robocopy. This would satisfy your need to not send a clear text password, and would additionally provide a more robust copy process than you currently have.

The permissions you need are whatever is required to allow the source machine write to the destination. As for ports, it's whatever port you run the VPN over. For a simple Windows VPN that will be 1723.